# Establishing PHP PDO DB Connections

Tags: php, pdo

I'm new to using PDO in PHP and after reviewing some sample code I was wondering how best to handle db connections efficiently.

I have the following in my dbconnector.php to establish a connection. The echos are just test code:

```
try {
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $appusername, $apppassword);
    // Set the PDO error mode to exception
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo "Connected Successfully";
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

What is the best way to leverage this code in each class so I'm not stuck copying it into every function that needs to fetch data? I thought about extending PDO and just creating a db object as needed, but I read a few posts and articles that seemed to discourage doing so as PDO is already object oriented.

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense. You're working with classes, yet you have no idea how not to repeat a simple piece of code? That's very weird. I would say: Start reading your PHP book from the beginning.

Comment: Note that [you should never catch errors to report them](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#errors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I thought about extending PDO

This is a perfectly understandable rookie mistake. This, however, violates (at least) two rules of [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)): [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) and [LSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

**Single Responsibility Principle**: By extending `PDO` your new class has now coupled data access to whatever the new class is meant to be doing.

**Liskov substitution principle**: By extending `PDO` you are also declaring the new class a larger version of `PDO`, which it isn't. Any function that typehints for `PDO` (`function foo(PDO $pdo)`) will accept your new class as an argument - when in reality it shouldn't.

I think a case could be made for the **open-closed principle** too - but this gives you enough to think about.

It might make more sense for classes to work with output from that database rather than inject the entire database connection into class. That is, rather than force your new class to use a database connection, pass *only* the data it requires to the class. This is the most simple implementation.

That said, there are perfectly good reasons to need to inject the database connection into a class. However, doing this should be done with [dependency injection](http://fabien.potencier.org/what-is-dependency-injection.html). Here's a brief example:

```
class Foo
{
    public function __construct(PDO $pdo){
         $this->PDO = $pdo;
    }

    public function doTheThing(){
         $this->PDO->query(/* do whatever */);
         // ...
    }
}

$pdo = new PDO(/* whatever */);
$foo = new Foo($pdo);
```

This way, you can instantiate your new class based on a custom built `PDO` instance and access different databases with different `PDO` objects.

If you ever need to take it a step further you could create a "data access" interface, create objects that implement it, and typehint for the interface. However, injecting just a `PDO` instance is a wonderful first step in the right direction.